# Multi dimensional array out of bounds

Tags: c#

My code is hanging on the line `fi_get[1, 4]` with an "index out of bounds" error.

The `lines` var is a string list array and at run time it had well over 600 lines of text in it. I don't know why I can't assign a string value to `[1,4]`? It does assign values to `[1,0]` and `[1,1]` and `[1,2]` and `[1,3]`.

```
    string[,] fi_get = new string[2, 11];

     if (lines[i].Contains("show fabric-interconnect firmware"))
            {
                fi_get[0, 0] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 2], @".+Running-Kern-Vers:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[0, 1] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 3], @".+Running-Sys-Vers:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[0, 2] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 4], @".+Startup-Kern-Vers:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[0, 3] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 5], @".+Startup-Sys-Vers:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 0] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 7], @".+Running-Kern-Vers:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 1] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 8], @".+Running-Sys-Vers:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 2] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 9], @".+Startup-Kern-Vers:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 3] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 10], @".+Startup-Sys-Vers:\s(.+)", "$1");
            }

            if (lines[i].Contains("show fabric-interconnect inventory expand detail"))
            {
                fi_get[0, 4] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 2], @".+Product Name:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[0, 5] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 3], @".+PID:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[0, 6] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 4], @".+Serial (SN):\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[0, 7] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 7], @".+Description:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[0, 8] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 10], @".+Serial (SN):\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[0, 9] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 13], @".+Product Name:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[0, 10] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 14], @".+PID:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[0, 11] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 15], @".+Serial (SN):\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 4] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 29], @".+Product Name:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 5] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 30], @".+PID:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 6] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 31], @".+Serial (SN):\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 7] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 34], @".+Description:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 8] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 37], @".+Serial (SN):\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 9] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 40], @".+Product Name:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 10] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 41], @".+PID:\s(.+)", "$1");
                fi_get[1, 11] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 42], @".+Serial (SN):\s(.+)", "$1");
            }
```

Comment: Is it blowing up setting the array value or reading lines[i + 29]?

Comment: There's two arrays in there; are you sure lines[i+29] is a valid element?

Answer (score 3):

An error I see is on `fi_get[0, 11] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 15]` because second index should be between 0 and 10!!
Same error on `fi_get[1, 11] = Regex.Replace(lines[i + 42]`.

To answer your question

> why I can't assign a string value to [1,4]?

Remember that C# arrays are zero based, so if you define `fi_get[1, 4]` you can assign values from `fi_get[0, 0]` to fi_get`[0, 3]`.
If you want to assign to `fi_get[1, 4]` you should define at least `fi_get = new string[2, 5]`.

Comment: thx i realized what i did before you comment sorry about that :)

Comment: @johnjohnson: did you solve your problem with my answer or do you have the same problem anymore?

Answer (score 2):

I would bet that it's this expression:

```
lines[i + 29]
```

What is the value of `i` at the time this runs?

```
i + 29
```

is probably out of range. It's the only array index out of bounds exception that can be thrown on that line if this code is accurate.